# how to start ob_start inside a class?

Tags: php, ob-start

im doing a little reasearch about minimalizing the html from php. like

```
class themeing
{
    function render( $file, $folder )
    {
        if ( COMPRESS ) {
            // this is the problem
            ob_start('compressor'); 
        }

        $get = VIEWS . $folder . '/' . $file . '.phtml';

        if ( COMPRESS ) {
            ob_end_flush();
        }

        return $get;
    }

    function compressor($buffer)
    {
        $search = array(
            '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/',
            '/\>[^\S ]+/s',
            '/[^\S ]+\</s',
            '/(\s)+/s'
        );
        $replace = array(
            '',
            '>',
            '<',
            '\\1'
        );

        $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
        return $buffer;
    }
}
```

the problem is how do i call this ob_start(function) ? can we do like ob_start($this->compresssor()) ? ( ok i know it fails ) inside a class? anyone ??

Thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: the proper term is "minifying" or "minification"

Comment: *(nitpick)* I wouldnt expect a Themeing class to be able to minify.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ob_start(array($this,'compressor'))
```

PHP uses an [array(instance,function) representation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) for representing member functions of classes as callable functions.

Comment: really thanks victor, stackoverflow is starting to addict. hehe.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static method, it can be accessed like this:

```php
ob_start(array(get_called_class(),'compressor'))
```